# Does VARCHAR has all the Numeric properties?

Tags: teradata

I created a table in teradata and specified `varchar` as datatype for all fields, however my variables contained only numbers.

When I tried using

`SELECT SUM(var1)
FROM thetable`

I was surprised that it worked. So, I am confused, are the numeric datatypes in teradata are simply special cases of VARCHAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, VARCHARs are strings and nothing else :-)

But SUM is an numeric operator and Teradata does an automatic typecast when datatypes don't match. In your case the result will be a FLOAT, because this is the most flexible numeric datatype.